# Create an NSDictionary from an array of path segments

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

What is the best method to build an NSDictionary from an NSArray of flattened paths?  For example, I want to convert this array's contents:

```
<array>
<string>packs/</string>
<string>packs/Children/</string>
<string>packs/Children/Letters</string>
<string>packs/Children/Letters/abc.pack</string>
<string>packs/Children/Numbers</string>
<string>packs/Children/Numbers/123.pack</string>                                    
<string>packs/Children/Numbers/10_2_30.pack</string>
<string>packs/General/</string>
</array>
```

...into an NSDictionary of the path segments and filenames, like so:

```
packs/
    Children/
    Letters/
        abc.pack
    Numbers/
        123.pack
        10_20_30.pack
    General/
```

Would it be best to first look for the array items with a file extension (.pack) and build the structure back from that point?  Or try to build the structure line by line through the array's contents?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your input data.  Some of your branch nodes (e.g. `packs/` and `packs/Children/`) end in slashes, and others (e.g. `packs/Children/Letters` and `packs/Children/Numbers`) do not.  Is that something you want to support, or are those typos?

Comment: Or perhaps the rule is simply: if the node ends with `.pack`, it's a leaf node.  Otherwise it's a branch node.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that all leaf nodes end with `.pack` and all branch nodes do not, for simplicity.

A dictionary is a set of key/value pairs.  It's not clear what you want the value for key `abc.pack` to be in the `packs/Letters` dictionary.  I'll just use the string `@"leaf node!"` as the value.

You can do this pretty easily with a helper function that inserts a path into the dictionary tree.

```
void insertPathIntoTree(NSString *path, NSMutableDictionary *tree) {
    NSArray *components = [path pathComponents];
    for (int i = 0, count = components.count; i < count; ++i) {
        NSString *component = [components objectAtIndex:i];

        if (!component.length) {
            // This ignores a trailing slash, and any double slashes mid-path.
            continue;
        }

        if (i == count - 1 && [component hasSuffix:@".pack"]) {
            [tree setObject:@"leaf node!" forKey:component];
        }

        else {
            NSMutableDictionary *nextBranch = [tree objectForKey:component];
            if (!nextBranch) {
                nextBranch = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                [tree setObject:nextBranch forKey:component];
            }
            tree = nextBranch;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of creating an initial, empty tree (`NSMutableDictionary`) and inserting each path into it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *treeWithPathArray(NSArray *paths) {
    NSMutableDictionary *tree = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *path in paths)
        insertPathIntoTree(path, tree);
    return tree;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better would be the first one in which you build the structure back by looking extension.

**Updated**
This is a simple example

```
NSArray *arrayPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"packs/", @"packs/Children/", @"packs/Children/Letters", @"packs/Children/Letters/abc.pack",  @"packs/Children/Numbers", @"packs/Children/Numbers/123.pack", @"packs/Children/Numbers/10_2_30.pack", @"packs/General/", nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *filePath in arrayPaths) {
        NSString *fileExtention = [filePath pathExtension];
        if (![fileExtention isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSArray *pathComponents = [filePath pathComponents];
            NSMutableDictionary *tDict = nil;
            NSMutableDictionary *lastDict = dictionary;
            for (int i = 0; i < [pathComponents count] - 1; i++) {
                if (i == ([pathComponents count] - 2)) {
                    NSString *key = [pathComponents objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSMutableArray *array = [lastDict objectForKey:key];
                    if (array == nil) {
                        array = [NSMutableArray array];
                    }
                    [array addObject:[pathComponents lastObject]];
                    [tDict setObject:array forKey:key];
                    break;
                }
                NSString *key = [pathComponents objectAtIndex:i];
                tDict = [lastDict objectForKey:key];
                if (tDict == nil) {
                    tDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                }
                [lastDict setObject:tDict forKey:key];
                lastDict = tDict;
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
    }
```